# Upload a local directory of images to a storage bucket via firebase-admin

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

What is the method to upload a directory to a firebase bucket via firebase-admin?

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET_NAME>.appspot.com"
});

var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

bucket.upload('../../images/**/*'); // this is just a guess
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single method to do this.  You will have to iterate all the files in the folder, and upload them all individually.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.5.x/Bucket#upload